# Spark Java DataFrame - ClassCastException when reading multiple files into multiple datasets

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am attempting to read data from separate files into separate RDDs which I then convert into DataFrames (using the Java api).

I experienced no issues when working with only one dataset using a single POJO, but I started to run into this as soon as I tried reading an addition dataset mapped to a different POJO:

```
18/03/17 00:58:28 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.ClassCastException: TestMain$PageView cannot be cast to TestMain$BlacklistedPage
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(JavaRDD.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(JavaRDD.scala:78)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:463)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The following is some test code that seems to replicate the issue I am having (using parallelized data instead of textFile input). I am using Spark 2.2.1. Is there something about the SparkSession I am misusing?

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("demo").getOrCreate();

        JavaSparkContext sparkContext = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

        JavaRDD<String> rawBlacklisted = sparkContext.parallelize(Arrays.asList("af .sy", "af 2009"));
        JavaRDD<String> raw = sparkContext.parallelize(Arrays.asList("ab .sy 100", "af 2009 10", "aa title 5"));

        JavaRDD<BlacklistedPage> blackListedPages = rawBlacklisted.map(BlacklistedPage::parse).filter(Objects::nonNull);
        JavaRDD<PageView> rawPageViews = raw.map(PageView::parse).filter(Objects::nonNull);

        Dataset<Row> first = spark.createDataFrame(blackListedPages, BlacklistedPage.class);
        Dataset<Row> second = spark.createDataFrame(rawPageViews, PageView.class);

        first.show(10);
        second.show(10);
    }

    public static class BlacklistedPage implements Serializable {
        private String domainCode;
        private String pageTitle;

        static  BlacklistedPage parse(String line) {
            String[] data = line.split(" ");
            if (data.length < 2) {
                return null;
            }
            return new BlacklistedPage(data[0], data[1]);
        }

        BlacklistedPage(String domainCode, String pageTitle) {
            this.domainCode = domainCode;
            this.pageTitle = pageTitle;
        }

        // getters and setters omitted for clarity
    }

    public static class PageView implements Serializable {
        private String domainCode;
        private String pageTitle;
        private Integer viewCount;

        static PageView parse(String line) {
            String[] data = line.split(" ");

            if (data.length < 3) {
                return null;
            }

            return new PageView(data[0], data[1], Integer.parseInt(data[2]));
        }

        PageView(String domainCode, String pageTitle, Integer viewCount) {
            this.domainCode = domainCode;
            this.pageTitle = pageTitle;
            this.viewCount = viewCount;
        }

        // getters and setters omitted for clarity
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i have just modified part of your code,now its seems to be working fine:

```
    JavaRDD<PageView> rawPageViews = raw.map(PageView::parse).filter(new Function<TestMain.PageView, Boolean>() {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Boolean call(PageView arg0) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean nullcatcher = true;
            if (arg0==null||arg0.equals(null)){
                nullcatcher = false;
            }
            return nullcatcher;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I wonder if the there's something up with using `Objects::nonNull` on the filter calls. I also found that replacing my filters with the following seems to work:

`JavaRDD<PageView> rawPageViews = raw.map(PageView::parse).filter(p -> p != null);`